# Add object in List ( Android )

Tags: android

i'm trying to put some intents in a List to a specific place but the app crashes 'cause of NullPointerExecption but don't understand why !

```
private ArrayList<PendingIntent> test;

[...]

try
{
     test.add( 42, alarm_Intent);
// I tried aswell without index ( it makes it crash too ) :
     test.add(alarm_Intent);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     Toast.makeText(this, ""+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Here is the error :

```
[2014-06-08 18:30:41 - ddms] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.read(Client.java:698)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:311)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

What did i do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
ArrayList<PendingIntent> test = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
```

Comment: yeay ! thanks it's working :D

But what does 

private ArrayList<PendingIntent> test;    do if it don't initialise it ?

Comment: test is null if not explicitly initialized. It's like in C char* ptr vs char array[3]

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `test`.

Do it this way:

```
private ArrayList<PendingIntent> test = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>;
```

Comment: I was the first I was the first!

Comment: I have one more sentence! :P

Comment: Watching festival starting

Answer (score 1):

initialise test array. `private ArrayList<PendingIntent> test = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();`

Answer (score 1):

You never called ctor of your array list and therefore it is null while calling add.